# Obtener cierta cantidad de archivos de directorio en Java

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con un directorio que contiene 4 millones de imagenes, y quiero listar las primeras 12000, solo que utilizando listFiles() me toma TODOS los archivos del directorio e imprime los 12000 solo que funciona muy lento, habrá alguna forma de tomar solamente los primeros 12000 en una lista?
Soy nuevo utilizando array o list.

Dejo mi codigo:

```
String ruta = "C:\\Users\\mxe02012231a\\Documents\\imagenes\\";
//String ruta = "C:\\Users\\mxe02012231a\\Documents\\imagenes\\";
String ext = ".jpg";
File carpeta = new File(ruta);
File[] archivos;
if(carpeta.exists()) {
    if(carpeta.isDirectory()) {
       archivos = carpeta.listFiles();
       for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
           if(archivos[i].getName().endsWith(ext)) 
               System.out.println(archivos[i].getName());
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma en la que puedes obtener la lista de archivos según el tipo de archivo que especificas y la cantidad de los mismos, es usando la interfaz [`DirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html).

Esta interfaz te permitirá iterar sobre las entradas del directorio (tanto archivos como subdirectorios), además, te permitirá utilizar un bucle [`for each`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) con el cual podrás recorrer dichas entradas.

En la documentación se puede leer lo siguiente:

> Un objeto `DirectoryStream` se abre tras la creación y se cierra invocando el método `close()`. Al cerrarse el `stream` se libera cualquier recurso asociado con el mismo.
>   Si no se cierra el `stream`, se puede producir una pérdida de recursos.
>
> La declaración `try-with-resources` proporciona una construcción útil para garantizar que la secuencia esté cerrada.

Una forma en la que tu código puede quedar sería la siguiente:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class listNFilesByExt {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    String ext = "*.{jpg}"; // <- Indica la extension a buscar, ver documentación
    String ruta = "C:\\Users\\mxe02012231a\\Documents\\imagenes\\";
    int limit = 5; // <- Aqui puedes poner el valor que necesites
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(ruta), ext)){ // el stream devolverá los archivos con la extensión deseada
      for(Path entry: stream) { // por cada entrada en el directorio
        fileNames.add(entry.toString());
        limit--;
        if(limit == 0) { // verificamos si alcanzamos el valor de elementos deseados
          break; // cerramos el bucle for
        }
      }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace(); // puedes usar cualquier otro método para manejar la excepción
    }
    for(String fileName: fileNames) System.out.println(fileName); //mostramos el resultado
  }
}
```

Espero que sea la respuesta que buscabas.

Comment: Hola Mauricio, sí, es exactamente lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!